# I am trying to flatten the array regardless of the level. I run it in debugger.it is working well until the last curly bracket

Tags: javascript, recursion

```js
function flatten(arg) {
  const d = [];

  if (!Array.isArray(arg)) {
    d.push(arg);

  } else {
    flatten(arg.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)));
  }
  return d;
}

console.log(flatten([
  [
    [1]
  ]
]));
```

At last step function would return me`d=[1]`.But `return d` take my code to the beginning and change all the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that each time the function is called again inside itself, it initialises `d` as an empty array, as it is the first line, so the value you had previously is lost.

In order to avoid this, you have some options:

- one would be to keep `const d = []` outside your function and you don't return anything. Each time you call your function, the results will be pushed inside.
- the other option is to keep the value as a second argument to the function for recursive calls, like i did in my answer for `flatten(arg)`. For your first call it will be `null` by default. Otherwise, if it is *truthy*, it will use the value in order to be saved in `d`.

*Note that I do use `d` as  second argument in the recursive call in this second option*

**EDIT:** I've added the function `flattenWithOneArg(arg)`, which demonstrates the first option I commented above. As you can see, the const `d` is declared outside the function, and the function doesn't return any value. It just pushes the results inside my outside variable

```js
const d = [];
function flattenWithOneArg(arg) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arg)) {
        d.push(arg);
    } else {
        flatten(arg.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)), d);
    }
}

function flatten(arg, result = null) {
    const d = !!result ? result : []
    if (!Array.isArray(arg)) {
        d.push(arg);
    } else {
        flatten(arg.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)), d);
    }
    return d;
}


console.log(flatten([[[[[['foo']]], [[[[['bar']]]]]]]]));
console.log(flatten([[[1]]]));

flattenWithOneArg([[[[[[1]]]]]]);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: thank you so much, I understand. I reset my browser. It fixed.

Answer (score 1):

User "vleonc" has already explained the problems with your attempt.  Here's some other ways to solve the problem:

This function [`reduces`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) an array into a new array, at each step [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)enating either the value or the result of a recursive call on the value, depending on whether the value is an array:

```js
const flatten1 = (xs) =>
  xs .reduce (
    (a, x) => a .concat (Array .isArray (x) ? flatten1 (x) : x), 
    []
  )
```

But [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) can simplify this for us, removing the need for `reduce` and `concat`.  This is clearly simpler:

```js
const flatten2 = (xs) => 
  xs .flatMap (x => Array .isArray (x) ? flatten2 (x) : x)
```

But we're not done.  It turns out that this is already built in!  The array method [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) does exactly this job.  It accepts an integer parameter and flattens arrays up to that depth.  If we use the parameter `Infinity` it flattens out any nested arrays.  So we come to this:

```js
const flatten3 = (xs) =>
  xs .flat (Infinity)
```

And of course this is now simple enough that we can choose to inline it instead of use a function at all:

```js
const result = arr.flat (Infinity)
```

I probably wouldn't do this myself.  I prefer working with functions.  But we should note that it's simple enough, and we may not want to bother with a function if it's only used once.

You can see all these in action in the following snippet:

```js
const flatten1 = (xs) =>
  xs .reduce (
    (a, x) => a .concat (Array .isArray (x) ? flatten1 (x) : x), 
    []
  )

const flatten2 = (xs) => 
  xs .flatMap (x => Array .isArray (x) ? flatten2 (x) : x)

const flatten3 = (xs) =>
  xs .flat (Infinity)

const arr = [[[[8], 6, 7]], [5, [3]], 0, [[[[9]]]]]

console .log (flatten1 (arr))
console .log (flatten2 (arr))
console .log (flatten3 (arr))
console .log (arr .flat (Infinity))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```